# Нанес победный бросок -?

Tags: семантика, лексическая-сочетаемость

> Нанес победный бросок

Это про хоккей - из телевизора.
Можно нанести бросок?
Вроде бы нет, но почему?

Что вообще можно с броском сделать, кроме "выполнить"/"произвести" - и т. п.?

Answer (score 1):

"Вроде бы нет" по одной простой причине: так почти не говорят. Удар – сколько угодно, а бросок – не очень-то. "Бросок" произошел от "бросить", как "удар" от "ударить",а "бросить" во всех значениях, кроме хоккейного, очень далеко от "ударить". Поэтому "нанести бросок" не слишком смотрится.

Comment: Ну мало ли, что "не говорят". Причина, по которой "не говорят"?

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81+%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=YyhNV-CfKMbVsAGw8pDIBw - это к вопросу "не говорят".

Comment: А вот ваши ответы мне регулярно попадают на проверку из-за низкого качества. Править я их категорически не хочу, ибо бесполезно. Как жить-то будем?!

Comment: *Причина, по которой не говорят?* Я вроде по-русски пишу, нет? А кто проверяльщик качества ответов? Может, что-то в консерватории подправить?

Comment: *А кто проверяльщик качества ответов? Может, что-то в консерватории подправить?* - нет, матчасть подучить.

Comment: *Причина, по которой не говорят? Я вроде по-русски пишу, нет?* - да-да, можете, конечно, по-русски ответить. Впрочем, уже не настаиваю.)))

Comment: Кто виноват, что вы по-русски не понимаете...

Answer (score 1):

Не сочетается потому, что то "нанести" заключает в себе смысл результативности (краску на поверхность, удар по мячу, рану на тело). О несостоявшемся визите не говорят, что его "нанесли" ("я нанёс ему визит, правда, его дома не было"). Удар не "наносят" в аут или мимо мяча, хотя и можно иногда сказать об ударе, "нанесённом" (по мячу) "в направлении ворот" - здесь положение выправляет другой аспект: то, что удар, нанесённый по мячу, переносится на направление удара мячом. В случае же "броска" действие не несёт смысла результативности: брошенное находится в полёте, а факт попадания требуется оговаривать отдельно, при этом "нанесение" чего-либо невозможно отнести к объекту броска (как в случае нанесения удара по мячу) и перенести таким путём действие с этого объекта на цель или направление броска.

Answer (score 0):

Из словаря:

НАНЕСТИ, 8. Причинить, сделать **то, что выражено существительным**. Н. ножевую рану. Н. урон. Н. поражение. Н. визит кому-л.

Нанести удар - ударить, нанести бросок - бросить. Из этого следует, что выражение "нанести бросок" не противоречит грамматике, к тому же оно, кажется, достаточно часто применяется на практике.

Пример: Уже в равных составах Орлов нанес бросок невероятной силы. На счастье норвежцев, шайба в ворота не попала.

Comment: И вашего ответа скорее следует, что противоречит грамматике "нанести удар". Как вы будете "причинять удар"? Даже у Кузнецова  таких примеров я не вижу. Или там другое значение надо смотреть.

Comment: Нанести поражение - это причинить поражение или сделать поражение? В этом случае эти конкретные глаголы тоже не подходят, поэтому  надо иметь в виду их общий смысл: осуществить, воплотить,   реализовать.

Comment: Это "причинить". А может, и "сделать". В любом случае, поражение - это результат. А не действие. Поэтому его можно и причинить, и сделать, и нанести. А вот бросок - это действие, некое движение.  Вот насчет удара - не совсем уверен, здесь скорее всего, если за пределами спорта, "нанести удар" - тоже результат. Соприкосновение руки-ноги или там палки-ножа. И результат этого соприкосновения. Если не попал - это уже не нанес. Можно ударить по мячу, а "удар по воротам" - уже некая условность, особенно если не попали. Вот как-то так. Я до конца не чувствую, потому и спрашиваю.

Comment: Совершенный вид глагола - это уже результат. БРОСИТЬ,  св. 1. кого-что. Резким движением, взмахом руки заставить переместиться по воздуху, упасть куда-л. Б. мяч в кольцо.  Б. копьё.  А насколько удачно вы бросили - это уже другой разговор.

Comment: Нанести бросок - это спортивная терминология, причем имеется в виду бросок, направленный в цель (хоккей, баскетбол, рыцарский турнир), поэтому некая условность, подтекст здесь присутствует.  Например, можно бросать копье на расстояние, но здесь не говорят "нанес бросок на 50 метров".

Comment: *Совершенный вид глагола - это уже результат.* - не обязательно. Грамматически соверешенный вид это законченное действие, результата оно может и не обозначать. Но я вообще не это имею в виду. Результат - это то что получилось в результате действия.

Comment: *Нанести бросок - это спортивная терминология, причем имеется в виду бросок...* - это все очень интересно, но я имею в виду всего лишь семантику прямого дополнения при глаголе "нанести". "Нанести Х" - это не значит "произвести Х". Это значит придать некоему Y (кому или чему) некий Х. Как правило - вред, урон, ущерб или что-то подобное, но именно Y никак не самому X.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо. Дискуссии тут не приветствуются, вынужден замолчать.

Comment: *"Нанести Х" - это не значит "произвести Х"* Когда как. "Нанести удар по воротам" — это именно произвести удар.